Google Cloud Connection Works with Apex Auth Class but not with Named Credentials
I have hosted an API on google cloud run and the downloaded the service account credentials in below format.
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}

I have created a keystore and uploaded it in my org as keystorersa1.
I wrote an apex class that simulates the oAuth jwt bearer token exchange flow. I am able to call my API using this code. Credentials are changed in below code for privacy.
public with sharing class GCPService {
    public static void run() {
        Auth.JWS jws = getJwtToken();
        String token = getAccessToken(jws);
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://server-py-run-uip7fth8ty-em.a.run.app/');
        String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' + token;
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http http = new Http();
        try {
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
            System.debug(res.getBody());
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static Auth.JWS getJwtToken() {
        Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
        jwt.setSub('sf-service-account@blue-panda-159024.iam.gserviceaccount.com');
        jwt.setAud('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'); 
        jwt.setIss('sf-service-account@blue-panda-159024.iam.gserviceaccount.com');
        jwt.setValidityLength(60);
        Map<String, Object> claims = new Map<String, Object>();
        claims.put('kid', 'a60r5173610cbd32th13734a2478e67xt2c9hjc4');
        claims.put('target_audience', 'https://server-py-run-uip7fth8ty-em.a.run.app');
        
        jwt.setAdditionalClaims(claims);
        Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt,'keystorersa1');
        return jws;
    }

    private static string getAccessToken(Auth.JWS jws) {
        String tokenEndpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
        Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange bearer = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange(tokenEndpoint, jws);
        Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(bearer.getHttpResponse().getBody());
        String access_token = (String)response.get('id_token');
        return access_token;
    }
}

Now, I want to call my API using named credentials instead of manual code.
Below are my named and external credentials.


But calling my API using named credentials is giving me error.
code:
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:gcp_cred/');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

error:

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

This question is similar to: How do you use Named Credentials with a Google Cloud API, which requires a JWT to get a token?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
